# Angular 2 + NodeJS + Mongoose - post data from angular 2 to rest api nodejs backend. Node api logs: OPTION /url, POST headers doesnt work

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose

I have issue with posting data from angular2 frontend api to backend client - nodeJS + mongoose. 
On Angular2 client I make console.log using data, which I'am sending, and service display correct values.

On NodeJS backend I try also to console.log posted data, but I got undefined. Please look at code below, and try to figure out what I make wrong. I tried to this also with `Promise<>` and `Observable<>`, with same effect.

PS. GET data from NodeJS api via Angular 2 is working well.

PS2. Important fact, Problem exist, because angular2 doesnt make a headers in post or put. Every time, when I make POST Req, NODE Server logs `OPTION /login`. What that's mean?

Angular2:

```
signIn(data: Object): Observable<User> {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(data);

    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log("data: ", data, "\nbodyString: ", bodyString, "\nHeaders: ", headers, "\nOptions: ");

    return this.http
        .post( this.signInUrl, bodyString, {headers: headers})
        .map( (res:Response) => res.json() )
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

}
```

NodeJS:

```
[...]
// configure app
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var Test        = require('./model/test');
var User        = require('./model/user.schema');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/lounge');

app.set('secret', config.secret);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});    
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
        console.log("Recived login request!", req.body);
    });
[...]
```

Comment: It should work everything is there.Can you make extended value false. `extended: false`

Comment: Thanks for comment, where should I pass value extended: false?

Comment: In this line app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); set false

Comment: I had changed this, but without result. When I make POST request from "POSTMAN", it is ok and node Server shows req.body correctly.

Comment: did you manage to make this work ? I am stuck in a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you are making the post request by not using the RequestOptions object you created.

```
signIn(data: Object): Observable<User> {
let bodyString = JSON.stringify(data);

let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

console.log("data: ", data, "\nbodyString: ", bodyString, "\nHeaders: ", headers, "\nOptions: ");

return this.http
    .post( this.signInUrl, bodyString, options) // **Change happens here
    .map( (res:Response) => res.json() )
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

}
```

The only change is using the options (RequestOptions) you declared instead of trying to define "{ headers: headers }" in the post method.

This is my first time post. I hope this helped and this posts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is at nodejs and angular cominication. Because they work on different port they can not comminicate. So you should add this code to nodejs as middleware and also ı recommend you to search "cors express" and "cors npm package". I hope this solve your problem.

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```